# How to save file without SD Card?

Tags: android, file, save

I have a device without a memory card and I want to save the file. I've tried:

```
filePath = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString();
```

/data/....   EACCES (Permission denied)

```
filePath = Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().toString();
```

/cache/....  EACCES (Permission denied)

and

```
filePath = Environment.getRootDirectory().toString();
```

/system/....  EROFS (Read-only file system)

is there other way?? (Sorry for my english :P)

Comment: Save the files in internal memory. Check it here http://connectcoders.blogspot.in/2012/12/save-bitmap-in-internal-and-external.html

Comment: [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29)? and check you app permissions.

Comment: Where the file will save? I have "null/xxx.png" but i can't find this

Comment: @Maury you can not see the files which saved in internal memory. If you want to see then save it in external memory.

Comment: So how to do that and save and see the file? (without card of course :P)

Comment: I guess it is not possible to view visually those files which saved in interval memory please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write file into internal storage, in your apps local space, file will be written somewhere like , below code may help you in this regard

```
            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
            try{
                fOut = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                osw.write("yourString data");
                osw.close();
                fOut.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save file in internal memory but you can not see the files which saved in internal memory.

Use this code to save the file in internal memory.

```
public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image,Context context)
{
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("photo.jpg", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                        // 100 means no compression, the lower you go, the stronger the compression
        fos.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Read this [article](http://connectcoders.blogspot.in/2012/12/save-bitmap-in-internal-and-external.html) to Save file in internal and external memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. I m using this for storing download images

```
String cacheDir= 
context.getCacheDir();
File file= new File(cacheDir,
"test.dat");
FileOutputStream out = new
FileOutputStream(file);
```